# Mongo Bulk Insert Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am working on understanding Mongo's bulk insert method. I want to insert records that have a unique index, and the duplicates simply get skipped over. I understand I will need an unorded bulk insert, but am having issues with the implementation. I already have logic that has been implemented with .saveAll by mapping through and building an object. I am failing to connect the dots on where to explicitly insert into the bulk operation. Can I not pass my object, or do I need map each key to data. In the examples I have read, they use small objects and specify each key.

```
List<Employee> employees =
      people.getEmployees().stream()
          .filter(criteria)
          .map(
              e -> {
                return PersonObject.builder()
                    .firstName(person.getFirstName())
                    .lastName(person.getLastName())
                    .gender(person.getGender())
                    .salary(employee.getSalary())
                    .weight(person.getWeight())
                    .height(person.getHeight())
                    .school(Schools.SEC)
                    .family(familyOrgins.getFamily())
                    .hairColor(familyOrgins.getHairColor())
                    .eyeColor(familyOrgins.getEyeColor())
                    .city(city)
                    .state(state)
                    .country(country)
                    .build();
              })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
          result = employeesRepository.saveAll(employees);
```

I have tried to inserting after the list of objects has been created like below:

```
      .build();
          })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
      BulkWriteResult mongoResult = bulkWrite(itemLocations, false);`
```

I want to insert using a bulk and if last name is the same, then skip over that person insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very small program that performs an Ordered bulkWrite using Spring.  You can change to unordered by changing the enum value on BulkOperations.BulkMode.  This program will insert 3 records, then delete one, then update one.  Because of the filter predicates in the later bulk commands I had to go with an ordered update.  If you are only inserting you could easily get away with a faster unordered bulk command.

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamongodb;

import com.mongodb.bulk.BulkWriteResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.BulkOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        // CLEAR THE COLLECTION
        mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), Customer.class);

        BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED, Customer.class);

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.firstName = "Barry";
            customer.id = i.toString();
            bulkOps.insert(customer);
        }

        bulkOps.remove(new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria("i").is(1)));
        bulkOps.updateOne(new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria("i").is(2)), new Update().set("name", "Barry"));

        BulkWriteResult results = bulkOps.execute();
    }
}
```

For completeness here are the other files in the project...

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/springtestBulkWrite
spring.data.mongodb.database=springtestBulkWrite
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-mongodb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SimpleMongoConfig.java**

```
 import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
 import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
 import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
 import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

 @Configuration
 public class SimpleMongoConfig {

     @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
     private String databaseName;

     @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
     private String uri;

     @Bean
     public MongoClient mongo() {
         ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(uri);
         MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
           .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
           .build();
        
         return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
     }

     @Bean
     public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
         return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), databaseName);
     }
 }
```

**CustomerRepository.java** (not really used in this trivial example)

```
package com.example.accessingdatamongodb;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

  public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
  public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
  public void deleteByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamongodb;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class Customer {

  @Id
  public String id;

  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;

  public Customer() {}

  public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format(
        "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
        id, firstName, lastName);
  }
}
```